# how to write a data from a gzip file to a GCS bucket using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying the read gzip file and put the same data in GCS in unzipped format . I am able to read the data but not able to put the same in bucket in unzipped format. Can anyone help me regarding this . below is the code .Variable "res" has data from zipped file

```
blob = bucket.blob('sftp/poc/TEST_3.dat.gz')
downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_bytes()
print(downloaded_blob)
buff = BytesIO (downloaded_blob) # put    content into file object
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buff)
print('Lots    of content here 8')
res = f.read().decode('utf-8')
print(res)
```

last statement gives me below data

```
header1
abc,xyz,pqr
```

I want to put this data in separate file in the bucket

i tried using statement but it gave too many errors:

```
blob.upload_from_string(res,content_type='text')


error
    message": "Provided CRC32C \"TjQbeA==\" doesn't match calculated CRC32C \"tDXRSA==\".",
    "message": "Provided MD5 hash \"hUglr3YB9TbhejPDdOAaYA==\" doesn't match calculated MD5 hash \"qk5UY/FTXa8asu8/KZFyDA==\".",
    "message": "Content-Type specified in the upload (text) does not match Content-Type specified in metadata
```

Comment: I would suggest to start with checking if the service account under which this code is executed, has relevant IAM roles/permissions in regards to the target storage bucket.

Comment: Can you provide some more context, and some details on error you get, please?

Comment: @al-dann , thanks for response . actually i am not getting actually statement to achive my task

Comment: Not sure I understand. Did you try https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html and "upload_from_string" function, for example?

Comment: yes i tried that but it gives me multiple errors. i have updated the question for the errors

Comment: would you like to overwrite the blob (as in your example), or create a new one?

Comment: @al-dann, i would like to create a new blob

Comment: In that case, the blob should have a different name, and it should be really new... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample  https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_string so you might need to have "tgt_blob = bucket.blob('<something here>')", and then "tgt_blob.upload_from_string(res,content_type='text')" in the most simple case

Comment: @ al-dann , thanks for response . i declare the another bolb variable and used that for saving data in GCS. it worked fine